# How do I use the correct version of Ruby?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, bundler

I've already run `bundle`.

```
C:\Users\Chloe\workspace>rails -v
Your Ruby version is 2.3.1, but your Gemfile specified ~> 2.4.0

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace>ruby -v
ruby 2.4.2p198 (2017-09-14 revision 59899) [x64-mingw32]

C:\Users\Chloe\workspace>path
PATH=C:\ruby24\bin;...
```

Comment: you can use [rvm](https://github.com/rvm/rvm) or [rbenv](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv)

Comment: try closing and reopening the command line. And also recommend what rogelio said, using rvm. It helps you switch back and forth many ruby version,s easily, from the command line, among other things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I still had `C:\ruby23` in my path. I removed it, closed & reopened the shell, and now `rails` was not found. `rails` must have been using `2.3`. I ran `bundle` again and noticed

```
MSYS2 could not be found. Please run 'ridk install'
or download and install MSYS2 manually from https://msys2.github.io/
```

A few times. I ran the installer `ridk install` (even though I already had DevKit installed). I ran `bundle` again. But that caused an error

```
Gem::InstallError: nokogiri requires Ruby version < 2.4, >= 2.1.0.
An error occurred while installing nokogiri (1.7.0.1), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install nokogiri -v '1.7.0.1'` succeeds before bundling.
```

I ran `gem install rails -v 5.0.2` (same version as my `Gemfile`) and it installed fine, using Nokogiri 1.8.1

```
Fetching: nokogiri-1.8.1-x64-mingw32.gem (100%)
Nokogiri is built with the packaged libraries: libxml2-2.9.5, libxslt-1.1.30, zlib-1.2.11, libiconv-1.15.
Successfully installed nokogiri-1.8.1-x64-mingw32
```

However `bundle` still fails and still tries to install Nokogiri 1.7.0.1, and `rails -v` still fails with an error saying it cannot find Nokogiri 1.7.0.1.

Now this is a new question so I'll create a new post.

Answer (score 0):

I would control your ruby versions using asdf or rvm. These are programming language version control programs which allow you to have multiple versions of a language on your system and control which version is applicable under which project. Here are the links:

https://github.com/asdf-vm/asdf

https://rvm.io

they are actually very simple to use after a short time. I prefer asdf but if you only use ruby rvm is sufficient.

Comment: That's not for Windows.

Comment: Ah yes, I didn't read the path properly, sorry. If you are going to be developing a lot I suggest switching to a mac or installing a linux distribution, your life will become much easier (except for gaming but that's getting better).

Answer (score 0):

```
 cd project/dir
 touch .ruby-version
 echo "ruby-x.x.x" > .ruby-version
```

create .ruby-version file inside your project directory and copy actual ruby version in this file.

This version will get selected as soon as you "cd' into the "project/dir".

Tried and tested only on mac with rvm as a version manager.

you can also specify ruby version in your Gemfile as below (not tested).

```
  ruby 2.x.x
```